# Kivy Button changing values unwantedly (size_hint)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

So, i've been studying the kivy library for a couple of days and I did a simple app with some screens simulating a SignIn/Register enviroment. What i noticed is, in my .kv file, when I set "global parameters" to my widgets, the Button parameters are simply not changing. Take a look:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

Gerencia:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    TelaDeLogin:
    TelaDeCadastro:
    TelaEsqueci:
    TelaEmDesenvolvimento:

<Button>:
    size_hint: 1, 0.1
    font_size: 40
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1

<Label>:
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
    color: 1, 1, 0, 1
    font_size: 40 

<TextInput>:
    multiline: False
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.1


<TelaDeLogin>:
    name: "Login"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = "Desenvolvimento"
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0.2}
            text: 'Logar'

        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = "Esqueci"
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0.1}
            text: 'Esqueci a senha'

        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = "Cadastro" 
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0}
            text: 'Cadastre-se'

        Label:
            text: "Usuário"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'y':0.8}

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'y':0.7}

        Label:
            text: "Senha"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'y':0.6}

        TextInput:
            password: True
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'y':0.5}
```

I'm ommiting some other screens but they are irrelevant, what happened was, I did some tests and changing the size_hint inside of "<"Button">" doesn't affect the size of my Buttons at all, they are apparently just getting some default size. Another weird thing that happened was, just to test, I did some changes to font_size both inside "<"Button">" and inside "<"Label">", and the value I put into Label also affected my Buttons on the screen, same happened with color. So it seems like my Buttons are getting their values from "<"Label">" and not from "<"Button>". Does anyone have any Idea what's going on?

Comment: Just to clarify, apparently you can't put text inside "<" and ">" here. That's why they are in quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

You have overwritten the base class Label, and Button is a Label as specified in the following Kivy documentation. In your Kivy App, Button has inherited the *size_hint*, *font_size* and *color* from your customized Label.

[Button](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html)

> The Button is a Label with associated actions that are triggered when
>   the button is pressed (or released after a click/touch). To configure
>   the button, the same properties (padding, font_size, etc) and sizing 
>   system are used as for the Label class

## Solution

Create dynamic classes for Label and Button.

1. Create a dynamic class with inheritance from Button. Replace instantied children, `Button:` with `MyButton:`
2. Create a dynamic class with inheritance from Label. Replace instantied children, `Label:` with `MyLabel:`

### Snippets

```
<MyButton@Button>:
    size_hint: 1, 0.1
    font_size: 40
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1

<MyLabel@Label>:
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
    color: 1, 1, 0, 1
    font_size: 40 
...

<TelaDeLogin>:
    name: "Login"
    FloatLayout:
        MyButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "Desenvolvimento"
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0.2}
            text: 'Logar'

        MyButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "Esqueci"
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0.1}
            text: 'Esqueci a senha'

        MyButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "Cadastro" 
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0}
            text: 'Cadastre-se'

        MyLabel:
            text: "Usuário"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'y':0.8}

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'y':0.7}

        MyLabel:
            text: "Senha"
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'y':0.6}

        TextInput:
            password: True
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'y':0.5}
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Using Dynamic Classes for Button and Label]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, worked out just fine. It's also quite useful to know that i can set different parameters for the same type of widget.

Comment: Please remember to mark the question as answered by *Clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer"*.